# How to solve room issue with many lists or map?

Tags: android

Room issue:

```
error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type (androidx.lifecycle.LiveData<java.util.List<java.util.List<com.example.shoppingapp.room.GroceryItems>>>).
    public abstract androidx.lifecycle.LiveData<java.util.List<java.util.List<com.example.shoppingapp.room.GroceryItems>>> getAllGroceryItems();
```

Room doesn't operate
`LiveData<List<List<itemElement>>>`

I have 2 fragments.
`One with List<ItemFirstFragment> and second with List<List<GroceryItem>>`

Both fragments are lists with recyclerViews, but when I click on first element in List I send id and name to second fragment then I would like to show in the second fragment
list[positionFromFirstFragment] -> It will show the second list like:

```
listOf(positionFromFirstFragment) as -> List<List<GroceryItem>> will gives me List<GroceryItem>
```

The same problem with map:

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM grocery_items")
    fun getAllGroceryItems() : LiveData<Map<String, List<GroceryItems>>>
```

How to solve it?

EDIT:

GroceryItems

```
package com.example.shoppingapp.room

import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey

@Entity(tableName = "grocery_items")
data class GroceryItems (

    @ColumnInfo(name = "itemName")
    var itemName: String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "itemQuantity")
    var itemQuantity: Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "itemPrice")
    var itemPrice: Int
    ) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? = null
}
```

EDIT:
Solved
Just use map or one to many relation with proper query. Check documentation
[How to handle one to many entity relationship with room and recyclerviews?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70269212/how-to-handle-one-to-many-entity-relationship-with-room-and-recyclerviews)

Comment: The error is `error: Not sure how to convert a Cursor`, post your `GroceryItem`.

Comment: in edit I post it

Comment: Post your GroceryItems as well, that seems to have a Cursor

Comment: DarShan I do not understand.
I have put GroceryItem.kt -> data class GroceryItems, what do you need more?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Room TypeConverter to convert this object type to json. That is what Room can store and retrieve.

Add or update dependencies

```
// Retrofit
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.9.0'

//Moshi Library Dependencies
implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.12.0"
implementation "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.12.0"
```

Create a Converter class for Room Database

```
class TypeConverter {

    //initialize Moshi
    private val moshi: Moshi = Moshi.Builder()
            .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
            .build()

    @TypeConverter
    fun genreToString(lists: List<List<GroceryItems>>): String =
        moshi.multipleListsToJson(lists)

    @TypeConverter
    fun stringToGenre(json: String): List<List<GroceryItems>>? =
        moshi.jsonToMultipleLists(json)
}
```

Use these extensions

```
inline fun <reified T> Moshi.multipleListsToJson(data: List<List<T>>): String =
adapter<List<List<T>>>(
    Types.newParameterizedType(
        List::class.java,
        List::class.java,
        T::class.java
    )
).toJson(data)

inline fun <reified T> Moshi.jsonToMultipleLists(json: String): List<List<T>>? =
    adapter<List<List<T>>>(
        Types.newParameterizedType(
            List::class.java,
            List::class.java,
            T::class.java
        )
    ).fromJson(json)
```

Finally add your TypeConverter to your Database by using the @TypeConverters annotation

```
@TypeConverters(TypeConverter::class)
```